# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline ECR Push / Error parsing reference

Tags: docker, devops, amazon-ecr

I have created a release pipeline with a AWS ECR Push

[yaml code for the task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqU4Y.png)

The task end with this error

> 2023-05-25T14:12:25.8536626Z Pushing image 'D:\a\r1\a/containerimage/containerimage/image_docker_services_asset.tar:latest'
> 2023-05-25T14:12:25.8537273Z Obtaining authentication token for ECR login
> 2023-05-25T14:12:26.4910021Z Adding tag '213053943211.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/213053943211.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/YYY-sandbox-XXX-assetsvc-repo:latest' to image 'D:\a\r1\a/containerimage/containerimage/image_docker_services_asset.tar:latest'
> 2023-05-25T14:12:26.4913055Z Invoking 'C:\Windows\system32\docker.exe' with command 'tag'
> 2023-05-25T14:12:26.4938749Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\docker.exe tag D:\a\r1\a/containerimage/containerimage/image_docker_services_asset.tar:latest 213053943211.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/213053943211.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/YYY-sandbox-XXX-assetsvc-repo:latest
> 2023-05-25T14:12:27.2765831Z Error parsing reference: "D:\a\r1\a/containerimage/containerimage/image_docker_services_asset.tar:latest" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
> 2023-05-25T14:12:27.2915439Z ##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Windows\system32\docker.exe' failed with exit code 1

how can i fix this issue?

i tried different task configuration without success

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.